# JSF/Primefaces - Ajax request sometimes skips JSF phases

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, weblogic-10.x

Been at this problem for a while and I am kind of stuck.

Using: JSF 2.0, Primefaces 3.5, Weblogic Server 10.35, IE 9

Problem: Sometimes ajax request are not processed correctly and you need to click multiple times to get the desired outcome.

When I debug JSF phases I can see that after phase 1, restore view, the render response phase is executed skipping update model and the invoke application phase.
I have striped my application to the bare minimum and the problem still occurs.

xhtml:

```
<h:form id="searchForm" >
    <p:commandLink id="searchLink" 
        value="#{message['menu.search']}"
        actionListener="#{searchController.search}"
        update=":searchForm:searchContainer"/>

    <h:panelGroup id="searchContainer" layout="block">
            <h:outputText value="#{searchForm.searchResult}" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Ajax request faild atempt:

```
Request 
javax.faces.partial.ajax=true&javax.faces.source=searchForm%3AsearchLink&javax.faces.partial.execute=%40all&javax.faces.partial.render=searchForm%3AsearchContainer&searchForm%3AsearchLink=searchForm%3AsearchLink&searchForm=searchForm&javax.faces.ViewState=-2472092625767957060%3A2001152572050371116

Response:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><changes><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[3781425509483626748:3390680605459134566]]></update></changes></partial-response>
```

This only occurs in our test environments in IE9 and not locally or dev environment which leads me to believe it has something to do with the weblogic server and how it is configured or IE. 
But I am at a loss here and any help on where I could start looking for a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: That's usually as a result of either a validation/conversion error or calling `FacesContext#responseComplete()`. And this is happening only in IE you say?

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce this error in Firefox or Chrome. 
validation/conversion error where my first guess as well, but after removing all validation/conversion the problem still occurs. We are not “manually“ calling FacesContext#responseComplete in our code.

Comment: I have now finaly solved this issue. The problem was related to this:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/11/22/internet-explorer-post-bodies-are-zero-bytes-in-length-when-authentication-challenges-are-expected.aspx

Comment: You should post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be IE and authentication. Solved thanks to this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/11/22/internet-explorer-post-bodies-are-zero-bytes-in-length-when-authentication-challenges-are-expected.aspx)