# Double click needed for buttons for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a primefaces 5.2 running on jsf 2.2.8 application. I am running into a problem when IE 10 is working. When I click on an ajax button, Chrome or Firefox makes two requests. However IE only makes one request. The second request is for refreshing the jsf.js.

I have not looked into deep why IE does not refresh the jsf.js but in the end, the first click always causes no action since it seems to be updating the viewstate. I am guessing there is a problem with jsf and IE 10/11. This problem does not occur if I force the browser to IE=9 or IE=8 compatibility.

Did anyone encounter such a problem?

Comment: Please create an mcve. Might be that you have nested forms

Comment: I can but I don't know where to upload. No nested forms. Tried reverting jsf 2.1.24. Same result. Only thing I have is a filter to enforce IE to latest compatibility.

Comment: Upload? Just post it in here. But make it a real mcve.

Comment: For toy cases, it will probably work. I am not sure where it is not working or why. It works if I run it thru Fiddler but it does not work when I don't use fiddler so it's mostly a caching issue but can't be certain what's breaking.

Comment: Toy cases? So you mean you can't (or won't try to?) reproduce witha simple example?

Comment: I have found the problem not the reason. It seems to be due to being redirected twice. If I redirect only once on the entry to web app, IE works without issues. Not sure why it's happening but will try to create mcve when I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is resolved. At least I have not seen this problem. I have added Waffle for AD authentication. The thing is the filter only applies on the login page. The other pages do not use the filter since once session is set up, I don't need the auth anymore. However reading this post [IE Skips JSF Phases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181315/jsf-primefaces-ajax-request-sometimes-skips-jsf-phases) seems to be my problem. He mentions this post, [IE auth issues/Challenge Response](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/11/22/internet-explorer-post-bodies-are-zero-bytes-in-length-when-authentication-challenges-are-expected.aspx).

For me what helped is changing the filter to apply to the Faces Servlet rather than a single source. I have not run into weird problems after that. I might be talking to early but that seems to be the problem for me...

For me problem was, Firefox, Chrome works, IE fails and the only response back is the update of the view state.